# I'm having a problem with my Python socket program [WinError 10057]

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip

I was programming a simple client-server socket program that worked on two different computers.
The server is a desktop with a static ip address, and the client is a laptop connected to a Wi-Fi. Both are using Windows 10 as operating system.
I also opened the firewall port.

Here is my code.
This code works well within one computer, but WinError 10057 occurs when another computer(my laptop) tries to connect to the server.

server.py

```
from socket import *
import sys

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 16161
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
CLIENT_NUM = 5

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

serverSocket.bind(ADDR)
print('bind')

serverSocket.listen(CLIENT_NUM)
print('listen')

while True:
    try:
        connectionSocket, addr_info = serverSocket.accept()
        print('accept')
        print('--client information--')
        print(connectionSocket)

        data = connectionSocket.recv(BUFSIZE)
        print('Received data:', data.decode())
        connectionSocket.send('OK'.encode())
        connectionSocket.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```

client.py

```
from socket import *
import sys

HOST = '*.*.*.*'    # server's ip address
PORT = 16161
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    clientSocket.connect_ex(ADDR)
    clientSocket.send('Hello!'.encode())    # WinError 10057 occurs
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print('%s:%s' % ADDR)
    sys.exit(1)

print('connect is success')

receive = clientSocket.recv(BUFSIZE)
print(receive.decode())

clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: Are you positive that "server's ip address" is your desktop's local ip and not its public ip?

Comment: The server's ip address is not private ip(e.g., 10.0.0.0 ~ 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 ~ 172.31.255.255 or 192.168.0.0 ~ 192.168.255.255). and I have been assigned this ip address as a static ip.

Comment: The `connect_ex()` method returns a success/error code. What is the return that you are getting?

Comment: connect_ex() returns 10060.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it. I asked my organization to open the firewall ports, and the connection was successful when the firewall ports were opened.